# Change SVN Repository location in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I want to update the SVN repository location of my existing project in eclipse.

This project was initially checked out from Trunk, but has been recently branched out. I have unchecked changes and now need to go into the branch, and they are lot of them so do not want to checkout from the branch and merge the changes. The SVN URL points to the trunk and I want to change it to one of the branch.

I cannot use RELOCATE options as I have read it can only be used to if the DOMAIN or IP has changed but not the directory.

Any Ideas please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `svn switch` without `--relocate` (see [switching a working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s05.html)). In Eclipse: Team > Switch to another Branch/...

Comment: The menu referenced in this answer is on the project, so this is a project-by-project operation.  i.e. if you have 30 projects in your workspace, you have to repeat this operation 30 times.